# Maya ignores my doubles quotations

Tags: python, cmd, maya, mel

I'm having troubles starting maya from a python script with a mel command. Or rather I have a problem getting the mel command to run, maya launches just fine.

This is what the maya documentation says about starting with a mel command:

> -command [mel command]
>
> Runs the specified command on startup. The command should be enclosed
>   in double quotes to protect any special characters, including spaces.

Whatever I try Maya just ignores my doublequotes and gives me a syntax error.
This is my code:

```
import os
dir = "D:\exampleProject\maya"
os.system('maya.exe -command \"setProject \"'+dir+'\"\"')
```

I figure this would be read as this in maya: setProject "D:\exampleProject\maya" (which is what I want)
What I get is instead: setProject D:\exampleProject\maya which generates a syntax error in maya due to the lack of "" around the directory path.

Comment: You either want an extra `\"` before setProject or to remove one of the `\"` at the end

Comment: How about this: `'maya.exe -command \"setProject '+dir+'\"'` because how I read yours, only `"setProject "` will be sent as the mel command because that is the first quoted parameter.

Comment: @David Ruhmann Tried, didn't work. It starts maya and in the maya console sets is as:  setProject D:\exampleProject\maya (and get syntax error) without the quotations

Comment: @Mr E When I try your suggestions I get:// Error: line 1: Number of arguments on call to setProject does not match number of parameters in procedure definition. //

Comment: @user2832718  I would then try playing around with single quotations and seeing if maya would accept those. `'maya.exe -command \"setProject \''+dir+'\'\"'`

Comment: @DavidRuhmann Maya reads your line as: setProject 'd:/projectsTest/p1005_knl/001_dad/010_/maya' which is exactly what I need, if those pesky ' would replace themself with ". So close!

Comment: @user2832718  I noted on the mel documentation that it states that [`"Every statement in MEL must end with a semi-colon (;)."`](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Background_MEL_for_programmers.htm)  Try adding this to your command. `'maya.exe -command \"setProject \''+dir+'\';\"'`

Comment: @user2832718  Another idea would be to double escape your internal quotations and see if [MEL interprets it correctly](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Values_and_variables_Strings.htm).  `'maya.exe -command \"setProject \\\"'+dir+'\\\";\"'`

Comment: @DavidRuhmann The double escape did the trick! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer from comments

From the MEL documentation, it states that ["Every statement in MEL must end with a semi-colon (;)."](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Background_MEL_for_programmers.htm)

[MEL strings also require quotations to be escaped](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Values_and_variables_Strings.htm), therefore double escape the internal quotations.

```
'maya.exe -command \"setProject \\\"'+dir+'\\\";\"'
```

Comment: Except the parser really doesn't care if it's a one line statement. The documentation of MEL is, sadly, quite often wrong about things.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to set the project you can use the startup flag "-proj"

```
maya.exe the/scene/iwant/to/open.ma -proj the/project/root
```

[See the Documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/index.html?url=files/Interface_overview_Start_Maya_from_the_command_line_.htm,topicNumber=d28e16903)